# How do I create a macro that searches for a value in Excel and returns the row number of it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two sheets in a workbook in Excel. One of them is a background color reference for star temperature. On the other sheet, I want to make it so that whenever I type in a value (i.e. 4728) and apply the macro, the macro rounds this value to the nearest hundred (without updating the value), taking the rounded value and searching for it in the first sheet, returning the row number (i.e. 59, let's call this value r), and taking the cell (G,r), finding its background color, and copying the color to the active cell (the one with 4728 on it).

Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Comment: sounds like Vlookup to me.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).